# Linux kernel shutdown can cause driver to leave an I2C bus jammed

Tags: linux, kernel, i2c, iio

I'm using [ST's own driver](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Linux_IIO_drivers/tree/linux-4.19.y-gh/drivers/iio/imu/st_lsm6dsm) for the LSM6DS[ML] IMU.

If that driver is in the middle of accessing an IMU register at kernel shutdown, the I2C bus can be left jammed, with SCL pulled low:
[image: pulseview screenshot of jammed i2c bus]

This means that the final I2C write (to a PMU chip, hooking into `pm_power_off`) cannot always happen. Therefore the power sometimes gets left on.

I'm trying to understand where I should fix this.

- Is ST's lsm6dsm driver faulty in some way?
- Is the kernel's I2C handling faulty? (I can't think of a reason for it to ever leave the I2C bus jammed.)
- Is it valid for an I2C bus to be left jammed at shutdown and therefore invalid to call `regmap_write()` from `pm_power_off`?

Comment: The lines should be left in the idle state at the end of read or write. If the I/O is not completing there should be a log. Turn up console logging and capture with PuTTY.

Comment: Oh. No question it's the driver.

Comment: @stark Their code calls `i2c_transfer(client->adapter, msg, 2);` to write the register number to the address, restart and then read from the address.  Looking at the logic analyser, I could see the first message part but the restart and the second message part were missing.  Their driver was not in control at this point, as it had called `i2c_transfer()` with both message parts at once.  Does a kernel shutdown just kill drivers in the middle of function calls, implicitly killing what they're calling?

Comment: Shutdown normally sends "please terminate". Any current I/O completes, the device is closed, the process ends gracefully.  If it doesn't stop quickly, shutdown says "kill now".  Normally, I/O will still complete, but if it doesn't, then shutdown may do something drastic. Is it possible the process is ignoring SIGTERM?

Comment: And why you don't use the upstreamed version of it? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.208/source/drivers/iio/imu/st_lsm6dsx

Comment: The I²C communications WRT shutdown is very tricky in the Linux kernel. You may read this discussion: https://lwn.net/Articles/781173/

Comment: @0andriy I need the correct driver for the ST-provided Sensor HAL.  I have previously had issues (with a different ST IMU).  The upstreamed driver did not provide all of the /sys paths that ST's SensorHAL required, and which ST's driver provided.

Comment: @stark ST's driver is part of the kernel.  (They also provided a SensorHAL implementation.)  Do kernel threads get signalled with SIGTERM?

Comment: Have you tried to report upstream about this? STMicro guys are also active there

Comment: @0andriy I'll raise a GitHub Issue on Monday, thanks.

Comment: @fadedbee  I was referring to the user process which is making the I2C calls.  Once shutdown starts, there should be no more I/Os issued.

Comment: @stark the user process is ST's Sensor HAL.  The problem is that the driver's call to  `i2c_transfer(client->adapter, msg, 2);` only completes the first message part (a write containing the register address) and not the second (a restart and a read from that register), leaving the I2C bus jammed.